# Windows app or software for suggesting our own vocabulary list daily as little popup?

Tags: software

I need a software like eye saving software that are popping up after a while to keep our eyes healthy, but what I want to show in that pop up is, my own listed vocabularies that I gradually added to this software while surfing or reading something on the net. One word a day or can be configurable. I know there is memorizing apps like Anki, memorize and more, I just need software for Windows to repeat what I add everyday. Because this way I will will review those words that I have problem with while I'm working.

Does Google Translate have such capabilities? Which randomly suggests my tagged vocabularies in Google Translate?

Comment: this is a question asking for software recommendation. You may want to ask this on [softwarerecs.se]

Comment: can't you add things to Anki?

Comment: Also, since it is unclear exactly what you're looking for, how is readlang.com, an add on to your browser that can add words you click on to a flashcard list?

Comment: also try [languagelearning.se]

Answer (score 2):

This is a cool idea. Unfortunately, I'm afraid that there is no such a program like that. This would be simple in term of programming, but you need to do that yourself though.

Nevertheless, [RSIGuard](https://www.rsiguard.com/) is a great software for RSI that you may want to try even when you don't think about learning English. You can add your own messages and YouTube channel when the pop ups show.

[image]
[image]

Another tip: I put the words to learn as desktop background

Comment: I didn't know this, thanks. I'll check it. I also use the following software for displaying what I want on Desktop. https://www.rainmeter.net/

Comment: I see that there are many threads regarding connecting Rainmeter and Anki. Maybe you want to start from there.